# One property of a class is another class. Problem - when writing a class to the database, another class also tries to write, but it already exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reference, relational-database

I have a class `Organization`. They are already in the table and should not be overwritten and added.
The `VehiclesRegistration` class has an `Organization` property:

```
public class VehiclesRegistration
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When a class comes from a view (ASP.NET MVC), its `Organization` property is populated with a class with the correct only identifier and name:

```
vehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id - filled
vehiclesRegistration.Organization.Name - filled
vehiclesRegistration.Organization[other class properties] - null
```

In such a situation, at the time of writing a `VehiclesRegistration` class to the database, the `Organization` class also tries to write too to table `Organizations`. An exception is thrown because the `id` is not unique.

```
vehiclesRegistration.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
db.VehiclesRegistrations.Add(vehiclesRegistration);
db.SaveChanges(); // here exception
```

Before that, I solved this problem in this way (elsewhere):

```
ExampleObject.Region = db.Regions.Find(ExampleObject.Region.Id);
db.Entry(ExampleObject).Property("RegionId").IsModified = true;
```

I think this is a bad decision. Plus, it doesn't work for this problem.
English is difficult for me, I was forbidden to ask questions here, so please do not put any minuses. thanks

**UPD**
More info:

= DataContext.cs =============================

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    // Catalogs
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    // Additional
    public DbSet<VehiclesRegistration> VehiclesRegistrations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().OwnsOne(u => u.VehiclesRegistration);
    }
}
```

= Model =====================================

```
namespace Schools.Models.AdditionalInformation
{
    public class VehiclesRegistration
    {
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }

        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

= Controller ===============================

```
namespace Schools.Controllers
{
    public class VehiclesController : Controller
    {
        private DataContext db = new DataContext();
    
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "FullAccess, EnteringInformation")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,CarType,VehicleType,VehicleReleaseDate,EngineVolume,Weight,CarryingCapacity,Name,NameKaz")] Vehicle vehicle,
                               [Bind(Include = "Id,Organization,AssetAcceptanceDate,InitialCost,WearConditionInitially,WearPerYear")] VehiclesRegistration vehiclesRegistration)
        {
            if (vehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("VehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id", "Требуется поле Организация");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                vehicle.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
                vehiclesRegistration.Vehicle = vehicle;
                vehiclesRegistration.Organization = db.Organizations.Find(vehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id);    // ???
                vehiclesRegistration.OrganizationId = vehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id;                         // ???
                db.VehiclesRegistrations.Add(vehiclesRegistration);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

= View =====================================

```
    <div class="form-group small-indents">
        <div style="display:inline">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehiclesRegistration.Organization, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 offset2em" })
            <div class="col-md-5 input-group " style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                <input readonly class="form-control small-indents text-box single-line relational" data-val="true" id="VehiclesRegistrationOrganization" name="view_VehiclesRegistrationOrganization" type="text" value="@( "" )">
                <a href="" id="selector_VehiclesRegistrationOrganization" class="input-group-addon small-indents selector">
                    ...
                </a>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <input hidden id="sys_VehiclesRegistrationOrganizationName" name="VehiclesRegistration.Organization.Name" type="text" value="@( "" )">
            <input hidden id="sys_VehiclesRegistrationOrganizationId" name="VehiclesRegistration.Organization.Id" type="text" value="@( new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") )">
            <label hidden id="sys_VehiclesRegistrationOrganizationSource">Organizations</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Navigation properties will be added as well upon the DbSet.Add() call. Either let the navigation property be null, or manipulate the VehicleRegistration's entity state directly.

Comment: It is hard to understand what is the problem. Could you post the full code of all classes the you mentioned.

Comment: I added more information

Comment: You do not have to add organization object to  vehicleRegistration just organization id.